# How to print both Object key and value with Each block in Svelte?

Tags: svelte

I wanted to loop through the sections object and print out the key in `h1` and the value in `p` tag. I'm fine with enclosing this in an array.

```svelte
<script>
    const sections = 
    {"Title 1": "paragraph",
    "Title 2": "paragraph",
    "Title 3": "paragraph",
    "Title 4": "paragraph",
    "Title 5": "paragraph"}
</script>
    
{#each sections as section}
    <h1>{title}</h1>
    <p>{paragraph}</p>
{/each}
```

Comment: did you want something like that !! : 
Title 1  :  paragraph 
Title 2  :  paragraph
Title 3  :  paragraph 
Title 4  :  paragraph 
Title 5  :  paragraph

Comment: Yes, so for the purpose of this question I kept it simple. But it is actually a section. Think of it like posts. The heading being the post title and paragraph the post itself.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

you have an Object with multiple keys each with their values.

you need to convert the object into an array first then iterate over it

```svelte
<script>
    const sections = {
        "Title 1": "paragraph",
        "Title 2": "paragraph",
        "Title 3": "paragraph",
        "Title 4": "paragraph",
        "Title 5": "paragraph"
    }
    // Object.entries() converts an Object into an array of arrays, 
    // each sub array first index is the a key and the second index is a value
    // Object.entries({key: value, key:value}) => [[key, value], [key,value]]
</script>

{#each Object.entries(sections) as [title, paragraph]}
    <h1>{title}</h1>
    <p>{paragraph}</p>
{/each}
```

here is a [repl](https://svelte.dev/repl/9fb792271c324da5bf1df6ccc617a902?version=3.29.7)